# ~ Not working in URLs

Tags: 2010, master-page, global-navigation, current-navigation

I have a main site with several subsites.  I recently had a catastrophic failure and had to reload the entire content db from backup. That all went great and everything seems fine except my main nav located in my master pages for my subsites.  Here is my scenario...

*Main Site*

```
www.mysite.com
```

*Subsites*

```
www.mysite.com/sub1

www.mysite.com/sub2
```

In my main Nav I have several menu items like this `~subsite/folder/page`

This was functioning perfectly before the reload now my urls look like this...

```
www.mysite.com/sub1/sub1/folder/page
```

Instead of what they should be...

```
www.mysite.com/sub1/folder/page
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple fix, not sure how this got removed when we reloaded the content DB but instead of `~subsite/folder/page` I needed `/~subsite/folder/page` thanks to anyone who devoted any time to trying to figure out what the issue was.

Comment: if you have answered the question, please mark it as answer.

Comment: I can't for 2 days